# How can I add padding to divs without using a inner div with 960gs?

Tags: html, css

I'm using 960gs, and am trying to add padding to `div`s without using an inner `div`.

You see, if you add padding to the actual `div` it will break the layout created by 960gs, and the only way I have found to solve this is to create another `div` within and apply the padding to that.

I guess there's no problem with this method, I just find the second `div` unnecessary and I'd rather not use it... any ideas?

Comment: Just recalculate the width + padding?

Comment: That kind of defeats the purpose of using the grid system, although that is a solution, I guess.

Comment: Angus: No more so than changing the padding on individual divs since that will destroy the neat lining up that grid elements have I'd have thought.

Comment: Use border-box in box-sizing property. You'll avoid that the box growths when you add some padding.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't box-sizing work?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

> border-box
>       The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin. This is the box model used by Internet Explorer
>   when the document is in Quirks mode.

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the main drawbacks of any grid system. Unfortunately, to my knowledge, there's no way around the padding problem other than to add extra markup. As such, adding an inner div is recommended method (one that doesn't have a "grid_xx" class attributed to it).

However, if you're feeling brave (and ready for alot of coding), you could attribute padding directly to the child elements. Here's the code for the two solutions:

```
<div class="grid_12">
 <div class="inner_div" style="padding:10px">
  <p>This is some sample text</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Or you could leave out the inner div, and use the styles directly on the child elements like this:

```
<div class="grid_12">
 <p style="padding:10px">This is some sample text</p>
</div>
```

Obviously you could use CSS instead of inline CSS, but the principles would be the same :)

Hope it helps.

You could also have a look at the Blueprint or YUI CSS framework, but as far as I know they've got exactly the same issue.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, adding it directly to the child elements seems even more dodgy (excuse my Australian). It's a shame that the CSS box model adds width for padding, as honestly it seems quite illogical.

Comment: Something else you might want to play around with (although I've got zero exp. in this) is the :after pseudo property. I dunnow how well supported it is for older browsers though... Might need to start using CSS3 Libraries like Modernizr, CSS3Pie or eCSStender. And no worries about sounding Australian (but only if you can forgive my South African - Heh.)

Comment: Great idea! I think there's even a :child psuedo, so that could be a great way to apply padding to all of an elements children.